# 2d arrays and image smoothing in c

Tags: c, arrays, image, 2d, smoothing

I have to write a program that " will take in an image as input, represented by 2d array pixel values(for simplicity, each pixel can be represented by an integer). Output the resulting smoothed image by applying the mean filter to every pixel in the array".

I'm just learning about arrays, but I am lost as to how to even start this program. Whenever I search this topic it gets very confusing because every example or concept that I find is using or talking about actual images. Since my program is using integers, I'm having a hard time distinguishing what is needed and what is not. Basically I understand the premise(at least i think I do), each number must take the mean value from the 4 numbers around it, but outside the basic concept, I'm at a loss as to what needs to be done. Any help, suggestions, or examples would be great.

thanks

Comment: 1) 8bit channel RGB Images ARE composites of integers 0-255 in three layers, so what works for them works for you

2) You have a 2D image. Loop through the values I[i,j] in a nested for loop, and at each element perform the computation. Beware boundary cases

Comment: How is the program taking the input? A file? Hard coded variables?

Do you know how to iterate over arrays of integers? I'd start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key concept:

```
int values[20][20];
float intermediates[20][20];
for (int y = 1; y < 19; y++)
  for (int x = 1; x < 19; x++)
    intermediates = (float)values[y][x];

int means[20][20];
for (int y = 1; y < 19; y++)
  for (int x = 1; x < 19; x++)
    means[y][x] = (int) ( (float) (intermediates[y-1][x-1] + intermediates[y-1][x] + intermediates[y-1][x+1] + intermediates[y][x-1] + intermediates[y][x] + intermediates[y][x+1] + intermediates[y+1][x-1] + intermediates[y+1][x] + intermediates[y+1][x+1]) / 9.0F); //  Divisor is 9 because we added nine values and we're getting the mean
```

Now there are 4 corner cases: intermediates[0][0], intermediates[0][19], etc. and then all the sides.

The values were copied into "intermediates" first because I didn't want to put (float)in front of everything.

Answer (score 0):

0) Load the image? or are you given the integer array?

1) We start with a 2D array, generate a copy: `int I[N][M]; int New[N][M];`

2) Loop through the values:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < M; j++){
```

3) Do your stuff

```
New[i][j] = sum(I[i-1][j] + I[i][j-1]...)/4;
```

- note, beware (i or j-1) going < 0 and (i or j+1) > N or M. deal with these boundary conditions as you see fit.

Obviously this is the simplest way, but it looks like you're in a class so it should be fine

Comment: The assignment is kind of vague, I believe what is supposed to happen is that the user is supposed to enter how many columns and rows they want... the output then produces a matrix with however many columns and rows, then outputs the "smoothed" matrix. So far the program that I have takes in the users input for the columns and rows, and generates a matrix using random numbers. I'm just stuck on this image smoothing aspect.